# Red logs in npm console (JetBrains WebStorm)

Tags: npm, console, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Recently a problem occurred in npm console while running one of my projects.

Whenever I run `npm start`, almost every word is colored red even if there are no errors.

I have tried reinstalling WebStorm. I have used settings backup. I did reset git to previous commits where I know the colors were OK. I deleted and cloned the repo. I don't really know what to do because I don't understand how it happened.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack writes compilation progress to stderr stream... And it's highlighted according to **Error output** preferences (`Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Console Colors`, `Console`). ANSI colors are not interpreted there ([IDEA-137769](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137769))

Comment: But it was OK (white-green) text for months and suddenly it all turned red..? Is it an update issue of webpack? But when I type the command in classic console, the colors are as before.

Comment: nothing has changed in webstorm, so it must be a change in webpack. and it's only the issue in run consoles, terminal is not affected

Comment: I've looked into webpack file Stats.js and they do set green color there. The red color is just really annoying but I don't want to recolor errors. Errors are supposed to be red but the logs are not errors.

Comment: please read my response: ANSI colors are ignored when information is printed to stderr